# How can i put an OnClickListener to a Background?

Tags: android, background

*Hi, i have a flashlight app, but i can´t run it, idk why, i think that is the OnClickListener in Background.. maybe its wrong, or idk, i am newbie , sorry D:
Logcat: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Hersix/LogCats---Android/blob/master/FlashLight%20USA) (Nothing important i think)
I have other FlashLight and the Background OnClickListener is the difference between these apps.. But.. How can i put, that when i click The LAYOUT or BACKGROUND ( the same thing ) turn on flash ? :|

Here the code:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {




public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        exitByBackKey();

        //moveTaskToBack(false);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

protected void exitByBackKey() {

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Do you want to Exit?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            finish();
            //close();


        }
    })

    .setNeutralButton("Rate us!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

             {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn´t launch Google Play", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }


        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                       }
    })
      .show();

}

ImageButton btnSwitch;
 private Camera camera;
 private boolean isFlashOn;
 private boolean hasFlash;
 Parameters params;
 MediaPlayer mp;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not        
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //Intent Screen = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ScreenActivity.class);
                //startActivity(Screen);
            //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You can use our Screen Light :)", 
                    //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
        });


        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    toggleBackground();

    //Orientación de la APP Horizontal
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    //Codigo para que no se apague la pantalla :D
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();

            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
              //  RelativeLayout layout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
                //layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slender);
            }
        }
    });
 }


 // Get the camera
 private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }


  // Turning On flash
  private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
     //   playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleBackground();
    }

}


// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
      //  playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleBackground();
    }
}


 // Playing sound
 // will play button toggle sound on flash on / off
// private void playSound(){
 //   if(isFlashOn){
 //       mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_off);
 //   }else{
  //      mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
 //   }
 //   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

   //     @Override
    //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //       mp.release();
     //   }
  //  }); 
 //   mp.start();
```

// }

```
/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleBackground(){
    if(isFlashOn){
         RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
         layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.banderausa);

    }else{
         RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
         layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.banderausa2);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // on resume turn on the flash 
    //CREO QUE ES PARA QUE SE ENCIENDA APENAS SE ABRE.
    if (hasFlash){
        turnOnFlash();
} //else { 
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You can use our Screen Light :)", 
        //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //}

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
   getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }





}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `onCreate`, you can have a layout's `onClickListener` on your **outermost** layout as follows:

```
RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourRelativeLayout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    }
});
```

You might have to add `android:clickable = true` from xml or `setClickable(true)` from code.

Comment: I can´t because i am newbie, but i know that your answer is correct.
I changed the layout for a View and its Ok :P
Thanks!